# How can I see the whole file and also wait for more data to be added to that file?

Tags: command-line, tail

I want to read whole file and make it waiting for input, just like `tail -f`  but with the complete file displayed.

The length of this file will always change, because this is a `.log` file.

How can I do it, if I don't know length of the file?

Comment: you already know that tail is close to what you want. did you read the man page for it?

Comment: `less` has the "F" key.  Useful if you need interaction.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`tail` lets you add `-n` to specify the number of lines to display from the end, which can be used in conjunction with `-f`. If the argument for `-n` starts with `+` that is the count of lines from the beginning (`0` and `1` displaying the whole file, `2` indicating skip the first line, as indicated by @Ben). So just do:

```
tail -f -n +0 filename
```

If your log files get rotated, you can add `--retry` (or combine `-f and --retry` into `-F` as @Hagen suggested)

Also note that in a graphical terminal, you can use the mouse and <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> to scroll back into the history (assuming your buffer is large enough), this information stays there even if you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit `tail`. If you use `less` this is far less convenient and AFAIK you have to use the keyboard for scrolling and I don't know of a means to keep `less` from deinitialising termcap if you forget to start it with `-X`.

Comment: +1 Your answer appeared as soon as I posted mine and although mine works, yours is better.

Comment: I got the message while I was still typing that another answer was there and that I should click to refresh. Your answer would get the job done, but I would not be surprised that counting from the beginning ( forced with the `+`) is implemented more efficiently.

Comment: `+1` for teaching me about `+0`. You may want `-F` instead of `-f` for rotating logfiles

Comment: I think there's an off-by-one here. `tail -n +1` shows the beginning of the file for me, and `tail -n +2` skips one line. I think the number is the line number of the first displayed line.

Comment: @BenMillwood both `-n +0` as well as `-n +1` show the whole file, which is what the OP asked for. If you want to skip the first line `-n +2` would be appropriate.

Comment: Right. I read "count of lines from the beginning" as "number of lines to be skipped" or something, but if that's not what you meant then fair enough.

Comment: @BenMillwood I put some more info in the answer, you were right to point out that it was not completely clear. I find it easier to use `-n +0`. If you use `-n +1` you always have to do the mental check whether tail starts counting the first line at 0 or at 1.

Comment: @Anthon thanks! This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 40):

There is a way better way of achieving this:

```
less +F <file>
```

It'll show you the whole file, has the full power of `less` and will wait for new input. If you want to stop waiting for input, and read a specific part, you can stop it with `^C` and resume with `F`.

The `F` command is always available in `less`, if you decide to watch for changes while having a file open in `less`, hitting `F` will turn it on. Thanks to [hiergiltdiestfu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/109276/hiergiltdiestfu) and [wildcard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/135943/wildcard) for pointing that out.

Comment: This is indeed much better than `tail`.  Thanks for the tip; I would never have thought of using `less` for this.  Note for others: You can also just run `less <file>` and then type `F`.

Answer (score 4):

`watch` command should do that for you.

You can also try

```
less +FG
```

You will have more options with `less` command to scroll through your file as you say it's a large file.

Comment: Less also doesn't follow a growing file.

Comment: @Shadur, it does, that's what the `+F` option is for

Answer (score 3):

In addition to /u/Anthon's answer, you can do something like:

```
{ cat filename; tail -0f filename; }
```

That `-0` option to tail is equivalent to `-n 0`, meaning: dispaly 0 lines. But the `-f` will display new lines.

You don't need the braces `{ }`. I used them because sometimes you want to redirect the filedescriptors in some way. For instance:

```
{ cat ; tail -0f -; } < /var/log/messages
```

Noted by Ben Milwood: you could have a race condition where the file grows between the end of the `cat` operation and beginning of `tail` operation. But again, this is an "academic" problem to an academic solution.

Comment: If the file grows between when the `cat` finishes and the `tail` starts, you won't see those lines. Unlikely to be a big deal, but a reason to prefer the pure-`tail` solution.

Comment: I think `{ cat; tail -n +0 -f; } < file` would fix the race, because tail will print any new data that appears between `cat`'s exit and `tail`'s startup.  Of course, it makes the `cat` redundant.  The redirection only happens once, and `tail`'s stdin is the file descriptor that `cat` already read out to EOF, so its current position is where `cat` stopped.  You can test it by putting an `echo foo >> file` inside the `{}`, to create the race every time.